# Selecting choice option in skype channel botframework not working [C#]

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow, skype-bots

I have a choice list in my code as shown below:

[image]

If I try to click on any of the choice in Skype channel it doesn't gets clicked. In other channels its working perfectly fine. (Clicks and typing the choice)
In Skype if I'll type the choice then it will work.
Need to know why the click is not working in Skype channel.
Anyone has faced similar issue?

```
[Prompt("Can you spare few minutes to give your feedback? {||}")]
public FeedbackOptions? feedbackValue { get; set; }

[Prompt("Please provide your Feedback {||}")]
public string feedback { get; set; }

[Pattern(RegexConstants.Email)]
[Prompt("Please provide your Email ID.{||}")]
public string emailID { get; set; }

public string ReportRequest = string.Empty;
```

My feedback formflow is as mentioned below:

```
var parser = new Parser();
return new FormBuilder<FeedbackForm>() 
    // .Message("Welcome to reporting information!!")
    .Field(new FieldReflector<FeedbackForm>(nameof(feedbackValue))
        .SetActive(state => state.AskToChooseReport) )
    .Field(nameof(feedback), state => state.feedbackValue == FeedbackOptions.Sure)
    .Field(nameof(emailID), state => state.feedbackValue == FeedbackOptions.Sure)
    .Build();
```

Thanks & Regards,
Sheveta

Comment: Can you please add your code that is creating the choices to your question so we can see what that looks like?

Comment: [Prompt("Can you spare few minutes to give your feedback? {||}")]
        public FeedbackOptions? feedbackValue { get; set; }

        [Prompt("Please provide your Feedback {||}")]
        public string feedback { get; set; }

        [Pattern(RegexConstants.Email)]
        [Prompt("Please provide your Email ID.{||}")]
        public string emailID { get; set; }

        public string ReportRequest = string.Empty;

Comment: My feedback formflow is as mentioned below:
var parser = new Parser();
            return new FormBuilder<FeedbackForm>()
                // .Message("Welcome to reporting information!!")
                .Field(new FieldReflector<FeedbackForm>(nameof(feedbackValue))
                            .SetActive(state => state.AskToChooseReport)
                            )
                .Field(nameof(feedback), state => state.feedbackValue == FeedbackOptions.Sure)
                .Field(nameof(emailID), state => state.feedbackValue == FeedbackOptions.Sure)

                .Build();

Comment: Sheveta, I have edited your code into your question, but next time please edit the code into the question yourself instead of putting it in the comments. Stack Overflow comments do not format code well and they remove all newlines. And please [format your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: @KyleDelaney hi thank you for updating the question, sorry i got confused where to add the code.

Comment: What Skype client are you using?

Comment: Hi Sheveta, are you still working on this?